# Cant jump from word to word in Sublime text 2 for Mac

Tags: sublimetext2

For some reason I cant use alt and arrow keys to jump from word to word. It works in textedit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

It works fine on my Mac, press the "option" key and hit the right/left arrows